# Machine Learning Algorithm implementation in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

For a beginner in Machine Learning, if we have taken course from Andrew Ng's class, what is the correct approach to implement them?  directly using the scikit learn algorithms or implementing them from scratch using python?

Comment: Always use popular, widely used existing packages for serious analysis/modelling if you can. Their developers will have spend much more time and effort on implementing them correctly and efficiently that you are likely to, will almost always have more expertise in that area than you, and the algorithms will be battle-tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to **learn** the algorithms instead of applying them, definitely try to use python (or any other languages) to start from the scratch. The reason is that you may need to understand the optimization step in the algorithm (i.e., how to get the coefficients).

On the other hand, if you use the package or tools, you may not truly understand the key concept from the class (such as gradient decent etc.)